# table overflows the page

Tags: tables, longtable

I use `\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{report}` and the `longtable` package. Also I have

```
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
```

in the preamble.

I have some problems with the table:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{50mm}|p{50mm}|p{50mm}|}
```

(I've tried `{|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}`) but it makes no sense).

I'm very new to LaTeX and all help will be appreciated! What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating your problem.

Comment: There is no `14pt` option in the `report` document class.

Comment: tnx, you're right. I have `\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}`

Answer (score 6):

Your line width is 17cm: A4 paper is 21cm wide and you want margins 3cm wide on the left and 1cm wide on the right. With the shown input

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{50mm}|p{50mm}|p{50mm}|}
```

you don't get an overfull box. Indeed the width of the table is

> 150mm + 6`\tabcolsep` + 4*0.4pt = 163.215mm

as `\tabcolsep` is usually 6pt and the vertical rules are 0.4pt wide. But your example is *not* what you show, since it' obvious that the second column is much wider than the first one (I suspect 100mm instead of 50). If the longtable preamble is

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{50mm}|p{100mm}|p{100mm}|}
```

it's clear that the table will not fit in the line width. If you need a table where the second and third columns are twice as wide as the first one, you can do

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.8pt}|
                   p{\dimexpr.4\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.4pt}|
                   p{\dimexpr.4\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.4pt}|}
```

Actually the first column is not exactly half of the second (it's shortened by 0.4pt), but this shouln't be a problem. This table will occupy exactly the line width. Just remember that LaTeX adds `\tabcolsep` at both sides of each column.

You can play with this measures, as long as the sum of the factors to `\textwidth` is 1, or try with Herbert's trick if the first column's width must be computed automatically.

Wide and long tables often require manual intervention.

Answer (score 3):

try `\begin{longtable}{|l|p{50mm}|p{50mm|}`
or use package `ltxtable`

```
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
...
\begin{filecontents}{longtab.tex}
\begin{longtable}{|l|X|X|}
.. table contents ...
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\LTXtable{\linewidth}{longtab}
...
```

With package `filecontents` you are able to overwrite the external
file `longtab.tex`, which maybe of any other name