# Long tabularx doesn't break rows

Tags: tabularx

My long tabularx doesn't break rows when it runs to a second page. Are there any ways I can break long table? (But doesn't tabularx break long table automatically?) In this case, I'd like Par. 1 in the first page with chapter title and direction. Then second page starts with Par. 4. I tried `\pagebreak`, but it didn't work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Notes}

\noindent Some direction 
\\ 

\noindent
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\raggedright}X}
\toprule
\textbf{Par.\ \#} & \textbf{Description:} \tabularnewline
\midrule

1 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.  \tabularnewline
\midrule

4 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.  \tabularnewline
\midrule


5 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.  \tabularnewline
\midrule

6 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.  \tabularnewline
\midrule

7 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.  \tabularnewline
\midrule

8 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.  \tabularnewline
\midrule

9 & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.  \tabularnewline
\midrule


\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use longtable....? or http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable  which is supposed to combine features of longtable and tabularx

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181146/5001.

Comment: This absolutely should _not_ be a table (tabularx or longtable or ltxtable), set it as a _list_  and page breaking will be much better allowing breaks mid item for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) will not break across the page boundary. An alternative would be to use `ltxtable`, but this will only break at the table rows, not mid-paragraph. A more feasible alternative in this instance is to use a list, which can break at any position, even mid-paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Notes}

\noindent Some direction 

\SetLabelAlign{center}{\null\hfill\textbf{#1}\hfill\null}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=4em, labelwidth=3.5em, align=center, itemsep=\parskip]
  \item[Par.\ \#] \textbf{Description:}

  \item[1]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
    Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
    Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
    vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
    congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
    hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
    amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
    lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.

  \item[4]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
    Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
    Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
    vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
    congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
    hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
    amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
    lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.

  \item[5]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
    Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
    Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
    vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
    congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
    hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
    amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
    lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.

  \item[6]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
    Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
    Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
    vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
    congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
    hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
    amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
    lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.

  \item[7]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
    Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
    Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
    vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
    congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
    hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
    amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
    lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.

  \item[8]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
    Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
    Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
    vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
    congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
    hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
    amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
    lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.

  \item[9]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel dui mauris.
    Duis iaculis leo tortor, in facilisis metus tincidunt ut. Praesent id accumsan urna.
    Suspendisse aliquam adipiscing quam, sit amet dapibus nunc auctor nec. Pellentesque
    vel odio sem. Ut rutrum accumsan libero, ac ultrices lectus ullamcorper in. Nullam
    congue bibendum erat, quis venenatis mauris porttitor in. Donec dignissim ut nulla sed
    hendrerit. Duis viverra semper ipsum, ac pulvinar velit tincidunt ut. Praesent sit
    amet tempus sapien. Sed hendrerit mattis interdum. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra sapien
    lorem. Donec consequat tellus ut risus tristique imperdiet.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides a simplified way of managing lists and their items globally.

Comment: +1 for telling people not to use any of my packages.